# Expo Imagepicker asks for permissions but nothing else happens

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I'm using expo to build a react-native app. I'm trying to implement the expo imagePicker so the user can pick an image from their gallery or camera roll and use it on the app however after the ImagePicker ahs asked for permissions and I allow them, nothing else happens. Thee user isn't taken to their gallery or cameraRoll. There are no errors currently however imagePicker isn't working correctly. 
What changes do I need to make to my code?

ImageSelector.js file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Constants from 'expo-Constants';

export default class ImageSelector extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
  };

  render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          title="Pick an image from camera roll"
          onPress={this._pickImage}
        />
        {image &&
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionAsync();
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.android) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
  }

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Do you have all the permissions? As the doc says, "You will also need to add UsageDescription on iOS and some permissions on Android, refer to the Install doc.

"

Comment: @SujilMaharjan I don't have an AndroidManifest.xml file already to store the permissions, do I need to create this first? I'm using expo app.

Comment: For that, refer to the expo doc: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Expo, you don't have to use it. And you need the right to storage space.

You can run `expo install expo-image-picker expo-permissions` and get Permission `Permissions.CAMERA_ROL`

**Example**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Constants from 'expo-Constants';

export default class ImagePickerExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
  };

  render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          title="Pick an image from camera roll"
          onPress={this._pickImage}
        />
        {image &&
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionAsync();
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
  }

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Should I replace my code with this? @hong develop

Comment: @RJDdev This code is a simple example that I created to help you because you are using Expo. You can refer to what is helpful to you.

Comment: I can't up-vote it because I am new to stackoverflow although I've just ticked it.  I tried to add code from your example in order to get the permissions and I've updated my question with the new code. I am getting the error: Identifier 'ImagePicker' has already been declared so maybe there's something wrong with my code still. @hong develop

Comment: @RJDdev The module you called up has the same class name as you defined. The computer makes an error because it thinks it redefines the module you have brought in.

Comment: @hong-developer I see, I've changed the class name and import statement and updated my question with the error I'm seeing. There was ImagePicker stated many other times in my code but I didn't think I should change it in the other places because I think it's referring to the 'expo-image-picker'.

Comment: You didn't install Constants. You can run `expo install expo-Constants`

Comment: My example is using a module that I didn't tell you to install. To follow my example, you need to install a module.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've installed it now but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Can you show me your package.json and the code you used?

Comment: I've added screenshots to my question. I used npm to install expo-constants because yarn wouldn't install it but it seems to be installed correctly.

Comment: As I said in the comments, I didn't ask you to install it using npm. you remove `expo-constants` and run `expo install expo-Constants`

Comment: I did that because the command you told me to use didn't work. I believe the expo install expo-Constants command has  just worked because I have a different error now. Maybe I'll open a new question with the new error because I seem to have had several problems with my code.

Comment: @RJDdev Why did you cancel the check in my reply? Didn't you answer your question? The current problem is different from the one you asked.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this didn't work for me:

```
Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
```

I kept getting the following error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Failed to get permissions
```

So, what finally worked for me, this function is used to pick an image from the media library:

```
const showImagePicker = async () => {
// Ask the user for the permission to access the media library 
const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
  alert("You've refused to allow this appp to access your photos!");
  return;
}

const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();

// Explore the result
console.log(result);

if (!result.cancelled) {
  setPickedImagePath(result.uri);
      console.log(result.uri);
    }
  }
```

This function is used to take a photo with the camera:

```
  const openCamera = async () => {
    // Ask the user for the permission to access the camera
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("You've refused to allow this appp to access your camera!");
      return;
    }

    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();

    // Explore the result
    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setPickedImagePath(result.uri);
      console.log(result.uri);
    }
  }
```

Get the full code and full explanation here: https://www.kindacode.com/article/image-picker-in-react-native/